# Composer autoload not work properly

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have following problem: I have class Router (in project/connection/api/callbacks) and TestRouter (in project/tests/api).

Class Router is only Example and I don't want psr-0 or 4.

Router has this code on the beginning:

```
<?php

namespace Connection\Api\Callbacks;

class Router
{
```

Test class start with this code:

```
<?php

$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Connection\\Api\\Callbacks', __DIR__ . '/../../connection/api/callbacks');

class TestRouter extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    function test() {
        $variable = new \Connection\Api\Callbacks\Router();
    }
```

Then I got error class not found. Please where is the problem?

Comment: Your `namespace` declaration is using forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Comment: Also there's no semicolon at the end of the `namespace` line. Both of these issues should have generated `E_PARSE` errors before you ever hit a class instantiation. Look in `vendor/composer/autoload_*.php` and see if your paths are correct.

Comment: Sorry, there i had typing mistake. In code in namespace i have backslash and after namespace semicolon exist.

Comment: But if I check all three autoload files then i can`t find my added namespaces.

Comment: Then composer does not know about them. `composer dumpautoload` will re-generate the autoloaders based on the current `composer.json`. Does that fix it? If not, what does your `composer.json` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want PSR-0, but you are using exactly that function. The code comment for the `add()` method you are using to add your class to the autoloader:

> ```
> /**
>   * Registers a set of PSR-0 directories for a given prefix, either
>   * appending or prepending to the ones previously set for this prefix.
>   *
>   * @param string       $prefix  The prefix
>   * @param array|string $paths   The PSR-0 root directories
>   * @param bool         $prepend Whether to prepend the directories
>   */
> public function add($prefix, $paths, $prepend = false)
> ```

I wonder what keeps you from simply using PSR-4 in this case. Just add the necessary declaration to your `composer.json` file.

When it comes to PHPUnit, add `require "vendor/autoload.php"` to the bootstrap file or use it as the full bootstrap file if you don't have to do anything else there. It will make writing tests easier because you don't have to take care of the autoloading and adding the individual class to the autoloader. Also, you won't end up instantiating multiple autoloaders that don't get removed from the autoloader stack.